# Autonomous robots hardware structure planning

Tags: embedded-systems, humanoid

I ask this question to clear my concept about hardware structure of humanoid autonomous fire robot, Here is scenario a fire robot detect humans from fire, there are some vision cameras some temperature and smoke sensors which help to perform this task. Now a days in market there are many processors like `ARMV7` and `Snapdragon` which process tasks in any device and control the system i don't think autonomous fire robot use some kind of processors.

Does autonomous robots like fire robot use processors or micro controllers. Does it require `OS` or `Rams` environment? Like any computer system which use these kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vision will typically use as much processing power as you can provide. Large humanoid (human size) control systems also take a lot of processing power. It is common for a large humanoid to have at least two large computers (one for vision, one for control) or more. Also, each motor controller and many sensor subsystems will have microcontrollers.

There is no preferred OS that I know of. Linux with Xenomai or preempt patch seems to be popular and what I use. I would not be surprised to find vxworks, qnx, xPC or realtime windows running the current generation of humanoids. The PC doing the motor control will need a real-time capable OS (which all of the above are).

The Darpa Robotics Challenge last year generated a lot of good documentation describing various humanoid systems. You can find lots of papers describing in detail the computer systems used for many of the contestants. An example is http://drc.mit.edu/docs/2014_jfr_fallon.pdf

Comment: does these humanoid robots work with os like `linux` `windows` or it has its custom os

Comment: can you give me link of documentation

Comment: what are Vision tends

Comment: 'tends to' is english slang for 'has a tendency to'. I improved the answer based on your questions.

Comment: @hauptmech - It's not slang; 'tend' is a verb all on its own, meaning "regularly or frequently behave in a particular way or have a certain characteristic." Tends is the third person present form of the verb. Saying "Vision tends to use ..." means that "Vision frequently or characteristically uses as much processing power as you can provide." Tendency is essentially just the noun form of the verb Tend, so there's no slang or abbreviation, just a different style of writing the same thing. FYI.